# Написать поле модели/формы для хранения изображения в нескольких форматах

Tags: django

Нужно написать поле модели/формы для хранения изображения в нескольких форматах, в бд хранится в  JSON. Есть идеи?

Интересует. как объединить JSON и ImageFieldFile ....
Хранить данные естественно в формате примерно {"orig": , "formats": ["",]}

В одной таблице. изображения в одном поле

**UPDATE:**

```sql
explain select t.id, tm.image from testdb_modelwrelimage t left join testdb_modelimage tm on t.id = tm.prod_id order by t.id LIMIT 5000;
```

```
Limit  (cost=0.43..408.06 rows=5000 width=177)
  ->  Index Scan using testdb_modelworelimage_pkey on testdb_modelworelimage  (cost=0.43..300995.67 rows=3692016 width=177)
```

В двух таблицах, одна "товар" вторая "изображения"

```
explain select id, json_filed from testdb_modelworelimage order by id LIMIT 5000 ;
```

```
Limit  (cost=23.96..339.55 rows=5000 width=31)
  ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=23.96..935611.73 rows=14822696 width=31)
        Merge Cond: (t.id = tm.prod_id)
        ->  Index Only Scan using testdb_modelwrelimage_pkey on testdb_modelwrelimage t  (cost=0.43..221543.76 rows=3706222 width=8)
        ->  Index Scan using testdb_modelimage_prod_id_da771018 on testdb_modelimage tm  (cost=0.43..526868.88 rows=14822696 width=31)
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/123650/discussion-on-question-by-za-ars-------).